# Diagonal Column Headers

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, html-table

I have column headers with long text in a html table, and I'd like to display the headers at a 45 degree angle (similar to what can be done in Excel).

Is there a standard, cross-browser way to do this with CSS or JavaScript?

I started playing with css3please.com, but the rotation doesn't seem to work, at least in IE 7. Also, another issue is that CSS rotates around the center of the element, while I need to rotate around the left side.

Any pointers will be appreciated!

Comment: I haven't found a satisfying solution. For now my choice is to do a 90 degree rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/Z2HHu/1/

```
-moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
```

Comment: Thanks for the demo. Same issue as with css3please, I don't see the rotation in IE 7.

Comment: I don't think there's an elegant solution for IE7. Probably going to require some hacks.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to draw the text on a bitmap or gif and display that.  The main benefit is that it would work in all browsers.